# SQL query to remove script code from each column?

Tags: mysql, replace

My database table contains javascript code in more than five columns.

It looks like following

`*----*----------------------------*
| id | question                   |
*----*----------------------------*

| 1  | <p class=\"MsoNormal\"><b>Lorem Ipsum</b></p><p class=\"MsoNormal\"><span style=\"font-family: \'Times New Roman\';\">Lorem Ipsum</p><script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"//site.com/abc/def.js\"></script>|`

What I want is

`*----*----------------------------*
| id | question                   |
*----*----------------------------*`

`| 1 | <p class=\"MsoNormal\"><b>Lorem Ipsum</b></p><p class=\"MsoNormal\"><span style=\"font-family: \'Times New Roman\';\">Lorem Ipsum</p>`

Any help would be very appreciated!

**Update:**
Few columns have script code more than 5 times. So how to deal with that too?

See following as example:

`["<span style=\"font-weight: bold; line-height: 24px;\">10<\/span>\r\n<script type=\"text\/javascript\" src=\"http:\/\/site.com\/abc\/def.js\"><\/script>","<span style=\"font-weight: bold; line-height: 24px;\">20\u00a0<\/span>\r\n<script type=\"text\/javascript\" src=\"http:\/\/site.com\/abc\/def.js\"><\/script>"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really look into using an XML parser of some sort to handle this.  MySQL may have such capability, or possibly through an add-on.  That being said, I can offer the following solution which will remove one (and only one) `<script>` tag from the column:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET question = CONCAT(SUBSTRING(question, 1, INSTR(question, '<script') - 1,
                      SUBSTRING(question, INSTR(question, '</script>') + 9))
WHERE question LIKE '%<script%';
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Its work very well. 

Now, what to do if script code exist multiple times in column. See my updated question. Thank you!

Comment: @JigarGorakhiya You would need dynamic SQL or a user defined function for this.  It is too long for a single answer, and also MySQL is not the best place to be doing such cleanup work of XML.

Answer (score 0):

You can split your column by the query like this iff you have the same arrangement of a string as above :

```
   select SUBSTRING_INDEX(question, '<script', 1) question from myTable
```

Comment: This assumes that the `<script>` tag is always the very end of the content, which may not always be the case (but let the OP decide).

Comment: That's I used the caption for this.